# Почему передавая указатель в качестве аргумента(но не его адрес),изменяется его оригинальное значение и в вызывающей программе?

Tags: c

В книге Прата по Си , в коде вставки в очередь вызывается функция для копирования значения.

Переменные объявлены так:

```
typedef int Item;
typedef struct node
{
    Item item;
    struct node* next;
}Node;
typedef struct queue
{
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
    int items;
}Queue;
```

Cама функция вставки:

```
bool EnQueue(Item item, Queue* pq)
{
    Node* pnew;
    if (QueueIsFull(pq))
        return false;
    pnew = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (pnew == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    CopyToNode(item, pnew);
    pnew->next = NULL;
    if (QueueIsEmpty(pq))
        pq->front = pnew;
    else pq->rear->next = pnew;
    pq->rear = pnew;
    pq->items++;
    return true;
}
```

Функция для копирования в структуру pnew

```
static void CopyToNode(Item item, Node* pn)
{
    pn->item = item;
}
```

Вопрос: Почему же вызывая функцию таким образом `*CopyToNode(item, pnew);*` изменяется значение полей структуры pnew и эти изменения отображаются в вызывающей EnQueue?Ведь для того чтобы изменить значение нужно передавать адрес указателя , то есть прописывать &pnew и соответственно принимать его уже двойным указателем `Node** pn` в формальных аргументах функции копирования.То есть точно так же , как и в таком простом случае:

```
void change_a(int a)
{
    a = a * a;
}
void change_b(int* b)
{
    *b = *b * (*b);
}

int main()
{
    int a=5,b=5;
    change_a(a);// не повлияет на а внутри мэин
    printf("%d\n", a);
    change_b(&b);//повлияет
    printf("%d\n", b);// будет 25
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. *Значением* указателя является хранящийся в нем адрес. Никакого изменения значения указателя в функции  `CopyToNode` не происходит. В чем вопрос тогда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сами и ответили - "изменяется значение полей структуры pnew". Потому что это структура, на которую указывает адрес, хранящийся в `pnew`.

Смотрите - чтобы изменить значение переменной, нужно передать ее адрес - так? Но ведь `pnew` *и есть* **адрес**. И меняется переменная, находящаяся по этому адресу.

Вот если бы вы хотели изменить значение самого адреса, хранящегося в переменной - тогда надо было бы передавать адрес переменной, а не ее значение. Но в вашем случае адрес остается тем же, меняется значение в структуре по этому адресу.

Так более-менее понятно?

Comment: ,вижу в отладчике pnew со значением 0x00954f18 - это и есть адрес,поэтому взятие адреса & не требуется? 'Вот если бы вы хотели изменить значение самого адреса, хранящегося в переменной - тогда надо было бы передавать адрес переменной, а не ее значение' Вы имеете в виду, что-то вроде такого : &((*pnew)->item) ?

Comment: ,а зачем тогда нужно иногда брать адрес указателя ?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что если `pnew` после вызова функции должна указывать на другую структуру - то в этом случае надо передавать в функцию ее адрес. Адрес указателя (переменной типа "указатель на") берется тогда, когда надо поменять значение **переменной**, т.е. до и после вызова она должна указывать на разные места в памяти. Но это не ваш случай - вам надо изменить что-то в памяти, на которую указывает переменная, но сама переменная так и остается указывающей на эту память.